# Como colocar varias expressôes JSX no onload no React

Tags: javascript, css, react, dom

Tem algum jeito de colocar duas expressões JSX no onLoad?
Toda vez que tento colocar duas expressões ele não reconhece a segunda expressão.
Queria tentar colocar desta maneira :

```
<td onLoad={e < index.length ? e = e : e++}{i >= proximo_mes.length ? i = i : null}></td>
```

Comment: se pode colocar o exemplo completo de sua pretensão só esse trecho não diz muita coisa, eu particularmente não utilizaria `onLoad` porque acho que existem formas melhores de resolver, mas, sem o código na integra e sem um contexto fica complicado. A resposta em criar um `arrow function` não é exatamente por causa disso é que tem que criar uma função para solucionar esse problema e ai entra funções comuns ou anônimas

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basta utilizar uma arrow function, nesse caso ficaria:

```
<td
  onLoad={() => {
    e < index.length ? (e = e) : e++;
    i >= proximo_mes.length ? (i = i) : null;
  }}
></td>;
```

Mas recomendo utilizar isso em uma função separada e só apontar para a função, por exemplo:

```
const load = () => {
  e < index.length ? (e = e) : e++;
  i >= proximo_mes.length ? (i = i) : null;
}

<td onLoad={load}></td>
```

Comment: obrigado , eu implementei no meu código mas agora está dando o erro : Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression  no-unused-expressions